# Xamarin - A floating button outside of the application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im using Xamarin.Forms for a little project, and im looking for a way to add a floating action button that appears all the time everywhere (something like Facebook Messenger's chat head) , even when the app is closed, to receive notifications and show them to the user.
I did a lot of google searches but managed only to find the solution for native android in java and nothing about Xamarin.
Is this possible in anyway ? (My project is simple, no MVVM, nothing fancy)

[image]

UPDATE: 
I found a native view for Android that does the same thing: 
https://github.com/recruit-lifestyle/FloatingView

Thank you

Comment: Something like this? https://medium.com/xamarinlife/creating-semi-circle-fab-menu-or-quick-menu-in-xamarin-forms-295a31db5e15

Comment: if you can find a java implementation, then you can translate it to C#.

Comment: @MihailDuchev yes ive head of Fab Menus, but ive never seen them implemented outside of the app, i want something to display everywhere, even if i open the web browser, if i get a notification, i will see the floating button turn red for instance

Comment: A button outside of application? Can you add a picture or more detailed information to explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT , example image added

Comment: I don't know if it can be achieved in Android while I'm sure you can't do this in iOS. If it is a button outside of application, it's more like a system app.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i wonder how Facebook's Messenger app implemented it on Android, i ve seen a few apps use it, it looks like an independent widget (works only when the invoking app is on the background) and it floats on top of all other apps and the Android launcher as well

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i think ive managed to collect some clues, google has announced this feature im looking for (Bubbles), and another trick to do the same is by using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW + IWindowManager to draw on top of other apps i guess ? i still need to read about it more

Comment: Ok, if you find a solution in native Android, then you can do it in Xamarin.Android.